# How to use PHP to echo entire word with occurance of character sequence?

Tags: php, regex, scrape

I have a PHP scraper that scrapes URLs and echos out the material inside a given div.  I want to modify that scraper to check the html on the page for the occurence of a string, and then echo out the entire word the string occurs in.

My Current scraper is this:

```
<?php
$urls = array( 
"http://www.sample1.html",
"http://www.sample2.html",
"http://www.sample3.html",
);
foreach($urls as $url){
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="div1">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
echo $second_step[0]."<br>";
};
?>
```

I want it look more like this, only working:

```
$first_step = explode( 'eac' , $content );
```

With the results being:

1. teacher
2. preacher
3. each
   etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `preg_match` instead of `explode`:

```
(\w*eac\w*)
```

**Code:**

```
preg_match('(\w*eac\w*)', $content , $first_step , PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $first_step[1];
```

Comment: `$first_step = preg_split( '(\w*eac\w*)' , $content );` this excluding the words @Trim saying...

Comment: I tried it, and its echoing out huge chunks of data, and not just the word, and the data doesnt have the word in it.  This is what I'm trying:    $first_step = preg_split( '(\w*eac\w*)' , $content );
echo $first_step[1]."<br>";

Comment: Using your advice I came up with this, which works.  $first_step = preg_match_all( '(\w*eac\w*)' , $content, $answer );
print_r($answer);  Yours didn't work, not sure why.